# Different environment variables per war in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way to have different environment variables for different war files in tomcat?  I am using a 3rd party war and need to have multiple deployments of the same war but with different environment variables (so it loads different configs).

Comment: Does it **HAVE** to be an environment variable or is that just your way of expressing the problem?

Comment: the 3rd party code does System.getenv, so it has to be in there

Answer (score 2):

Ok, total crazy hack idea:

Implement a PropertyPlayHolderConfigurer (or use web.xml from Tomcat) for each app instance and load properties same name as you have for System.properties().

Then, create a delegate Properties class that contains both sets of properties. Then

```
Properties props = new DelegatingProperties(app1Props,app2Props)
System.setProperties(delegate);

public class DelegatingProperties extends Properties {

   private Properties app1Props;
   private Properties app2Props;

   public DelegatingProperties(Properties app1Props, Properties app2Props) {
        this.app1Props = app1Props;
        this.app2Props = app2Props;   
   }

   public String getProperty(String prop) {
       // begin crazy science
       String caller = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
       // this is where you get creative.
       // Do the System.setProperties() above so you can intercept calls to  
       //getProperty()
       // and find out the FQCN of the library class(es) that need these variable 
       // (use your debugger).
       // then implement the logic here to decide which of the 2 property sets you have
       // you will query to get the correct results     
   }
}
```

These are **SYSTEM** properties we are talking about and they are meant to apply system wide. Your library was probably developed when it was 1-app-1-jvm (or the developer is a tard which is also likely).

Can I atleast get props for creativity? :)

Comment: Yes, +1 for creativity.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy if you run two instances of Tomcat independently. I'm assuming here you are talking about the OS environment variables.

You can also set properties in Tomcat for each war/web app. That would let you run two wars in one Tomcat instance. But that's not what you asked.

Comment: Yeah, I need to set the value as an OS environment variable (really just needs to get into System.getenv).  I could try to set up two distinct tomcats (atm only need two different paths), so would I just do this in bin/setenv.sh or is there a better place?

Comment: Its really easy with tcServer version of Tomcat. You will have to Google around to find out how with vanilla Tomcat. I would probably just set up two shell scripts in inetd running the same instance of Tomcat but setting environment differently beforehand.

Comment: @ekaqu literally just copy and paste the entire TC directory

Comment: i have setup tomcat to just run two different processes where each process had the ENV setup before execution.  This is working for me right now