# How to run two WAR files with different spring profiles on a tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I would like to run my spring application two times, in parallel, on the same tomcat server. One time with a `production` profile and one time with a `dev` profile.

I also would like to build one single WAR for the two profiles.

I've successfully integrated profiles in my application with `@Profile` annotations. I've successfully deployed the two WAR files on my tomcat server.

What I need is a mean to activate a different profile on each of theses two applications, with the constraint that these two applications use a copy of the same WAR file and that the two applications should run in parallel.

So `WebApplicationInitializer` and `web.xml` seem not an option.

Comment: Use spring.proflies.active variable (either as a system variable or an application variable through the spring framework) to active the needed profile

Comment: Both applications should run in parallel. How can I set both values in tomcat configuration files?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652264/tomcat-7-application-java-environment-variables-jndi-less or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946814/different-environment-variables-per-war-in-tomcat

Answer (score 4):

For the record:

To activate the `dev` spring profile on the application in `application-dev.war`

Create a file `<CATALINA_BASE>/conf/Catalina/localhost/application-dev.xml`

With the following content:

```
<Context>
  <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="dev,server" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
</Context>
```

This set the `spring.profiles.active` property to `dev,server` for the application run by `application-dev.war`.

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26653238/1807667

**P.S.:** With `autoDeploy=true` in `server.xml`, the [configuration files disappear](https://serverfault.com/questions/192784/why-does-tomcat-like-deleting-my-context-xml-file) on tomcat restart.

Solution is to add `<Context reloadable="true">` in `<CATALINA_BASE>/conf/context.xml` but beware that according to [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) :

> This feature is very useful during application development, but it
>   requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use
>   on deployed production applications.

and moreover using `<Context reloadable="true">` does not solve fully the issue the configuration files still disappear for some restart.

**P.S.2:** There is no `docBase` attribute in the `Context` element, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914888/deploy-application-on-custom-host-of-tomcat).