# Tomcat: 1 war, deployed 2x, 2 configs

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration-files

Simplified situation:

- I have 1 Tomcat container and 1 WAR which uses a database.
- The database configuration sits in a properties file (*in* the war).
- I deployed the WAR 2 times, one webapp on contextpath `/a` and one webapp on contextpath `/b`.
- Both webapps *now* point to the same database (same cfg).

What I want is that each webapp points to a *different* database. So, the webapp on `/a` points to database *A* and the the webapp on `/b` points to database *B*.

How would you solve this? (without splitting the war itself)

Comment: Why not change the configuration files of each war to point to different databases?

Comment: @LukeBajada: I don't *like* to build 2 wars, just because one or two properties differ.

Comment: @Henry: env vars or system properties are system wide and thus container wide and thus not war-specific. Please explain.

Comment: @codesmith yes, you are right, would not work either. I was thinking about the case where the same war is deployed in different Tomcat instances.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946814/different-environment-variables-per-war-in-tomcat  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353040/how-to-run-two-war-files-with-different-spring-profiles-on-a-tomcat-server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by Tomcat's context.xml configuration without splitting your code.

You can define two context for example `/a` and `/b` and two different global data sources *"sharedDataSourceA"* and *"sharedDataSourceB"*. You can bind different global data sources to these contexts with same name like *"appDataSource"*.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  ...
  <Resource name="sharedDataSourceA"
            global="sharedDataSourceA"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            alternateUsernameAllowed="true"
            username="bar"
            password="barpass"
            ...
<Resource name="sharedDataSourceB"
            global="sharedDataSourceB"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            alternateUsernameAllowed="true"
            username="bar"
            password="barpass"
            ...
  ...
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Context path="/a"...>
  ...
  <ResourceLink
            name="appDataSource"
            global="sharedDataSourceA"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.DataSourceLinkFactory"
            username="foo"
            password="foopass"
  ...
</Context>
<Context path="/b"...>
  ...
  <ResourceLink
            name="appDataSource"
            global="sharedDataSourceA"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  ...
</Context>
```

Then in your code you can bind datasource to *"appDataSource"* by jndi lookup. Deploy the same war to `/a` and `/b` . They will work on different databases.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the current context programmatically and configure the datasource according to the obtained value. For example using javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath().

You could also load a properties file according to context name.

Answer (score 0):

[getContextPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()) was suggested, and here is a technique to use it with [getInitParameter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String))

As an example, if you had two contexts: "**/dev**" and "**/prod**" - both indentical - and you set up your **web.xml** file with entries like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>database_ip_prod</param-name>
    <param-value>192.168.1.10</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>database_ip_dev</param-name>
    <param-value>127.0.0.1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And with a method like this:

```
public String getContextInitParam(
        javax.servlet.ServletContext context, String key) {
    key += context.getContextPath().replace("/","_");
    return context.getInitParameter(key);
}
```

A call like this from a jsp or servlet:

> getContextInitParam(request.getServletContext(), **"database_ip"**);

would return **192.168.1.10** on the **/prod** context, and **127.0.0.1**  on the **/dev** context.